# Why is UITableViewCell reuseIdentifier (null) in initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableviewCell that is based on an xib that I would like to use for 2 separate reuseIdentifiers.

I register the nib for both identifiers in the table view controller like so:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[ExpandingCell nib] forCellReuseIdentifier:ExpandingCellIdentifier];
[self.tableView registerNib:[ExpandingCell nib] forCellReuseIdentifier:InfoCellIdentifier];
```

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I call one of these methods:

```
- (ExpandingCell *)infoCellForIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {       
    ExpandingCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:InfoCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];        
    return cell;
}

- (ExpandingCell *)expandingCellForIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    ExpandingCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ExpandingCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];       
    return cell;    
}
```

Each one is formatted differently and I would like to have that code in the init method of the cell itself rather than having to do it in the table view controller.

Then in ExpandingCell.m:

```
+ (UINib *)nib {
    return [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ExpandingCell" bundle:nil];
}
```

and

```
  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {           
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code

            NSLog (@"identifier: %@", reuseIdentifier); //logs: identifier: (null)

            if (reuseIdentifier == InfoCellIdentifier) {
                // configure for info cell...

            } else { //default expanding
                //configure for default cell....
            }
        }    
        return self;
    }
```

The problem I am having is that in initWithStyle: the `reuseIdentifier` is always null.
What am I missing?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish with this code. Why do you want two identifiers for one xib? It looks like you're trying to make two different kinds of custom cells -- why not create two classes?

Comment: I could, but it would be a lot of repeated code, which I was trying to avoid. Also, the nib file would be a pain to duplicate and then maintain. I guess I could make one a subclass of the other...

Comment: Where is initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: being called from? Are you calling it explicitly somewhere?

Comment: does it not get called within dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath: ?

Comment: It doesn't when I try it. You said that the reuse identifier is always null. Have you logged that in initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:? Do you know that method is even called?

Comment: yes it does, I will edit the code above to show where I log it and the response

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43973/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-michael-campsall)